# Force reevaluation of dependency property to coerce value

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I saw this [blog post](https://wpf.2000things.com/2010/12/10/151-dependency-properties-remember-non-coerced-values/) with this code:

```
        Person p = new Person("Methuselah");

        p.Age = 28;
        p.SuperOld = true;    // Age coerced to 999

        p.Age = 56;           // Age still 999
        p.SuperOld = false;   // Age now becomes 56
```

I have a very similar situation: When I change one property (in this example `SuperOld`) the value of another property (`Age`) should be coerced to another value (`999`). And when I reset the first property (`SuperOld`) the second should get the baseValue which was set in the meantime (`56`).

But I don't know how I should force coercion for the second property when the first changed.

Any hints would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want to coerce the `Age` property when `SuperOld` changes, then call `CoerceValue`. You can read more about it, at the [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-callbacks-and-validation?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#advanced-coercion-and-callback-scenarios). The key info is, that this method calls your CoerceValueCallback with the "baseValue", in your case `56`.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
    public class Person : DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty AgeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Age",
            typeof(int),
            typeof(Person),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(int), AgeChanged, CoerceAge));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSuperOldProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "IsSuperOld",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(Person),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), IsSuperOldChanged));

        public int Age
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(AgeProperty);
            set => SetValue(AgeProperty, value);
        }

        public bool IsSuperOld
        {
            get => (bool)GetValue(IsSuperOldProperty);
            set => SetValue(IsSuperOldProperty, value);
        }

        private static void AgeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private static object CoerceAge(DependencyObject d, object basevalue)
        {
            var person = (Person)d;
            if (person.IsSuperOld)
            {
                return 999;
            }

            return basevalue;
        }

        private static void IsSuperOldChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            d.CoerceValue(AgeProperty);
        }
    }
```

And this is the NUnit-Test:

```
    [Test]
    public void Should_work_like_in_blog()
    {
        Person p = new Person();

        p.Age = 28;
        p.IsSuperOld = true;    // Age coerced to 999

        Assert.That(p.Age, Is.EqualTo(999));

        p.Age = 56;           // Age still 999
        p.IsSuperOld = false;   // Age now becomes 56

        Assert.That(p.Age, Is.EqualTo(56));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a backing field and have the property getter evaluate the other property:

```
{
    private int _age;
    public int Age
    {
        get => SuperOld ? 999 : _age;
        set => _age = value;
    }

    public bool SuperOld { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: and now image it has to be a dependency propery. e.g. for binding purposes